# How to place favicon icon inside select input box

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to insert a `fa-chevron` icon inside my dropdown box but it's not working, it's displaying outside the box.

I've tried changing the margins but that doesn't work.

This is when `margin-right` is set to 200:

[image]

And this is without margins:

[image]

Code:

```
<div class="col-md-8 d-flex" style="margin-top: -25px">
    <select name="carlist" form="carform" class="form-control" id="exploreNeighbour" style="z-index: 2">
        <option value="">I have no idea</option>
        {% for venue in venue_category %}
        <option value="{{ venue.name }}">{{ venue.name }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <i class="fas fa-chevron-down" style="pointer-events: none; z-index: 1; margin-right: 20px"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: what are you trying to do ..?

Comment: I want fa-chevron-down is in downdown box

Comment: You can try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55679610/7974621

Answer (score 2):

add z-index: 2; and  margin-left: -20px; to fa-chevron-down

Answer (score 2):

#### Problem

`z-index` is a CSS property that has some criteria that must be adhered to:

1. The element (aka tag) must have `position` at either: `relative`, `absolute`, or `fixed`.
2. Since `<i>` is being moved to float over other tags, the parent tag of `<i>` (ie `<div>`) needs to have `position: relative` and the `<i>` should have `position: absolute`
3. Any `posab` (`position: absolute`) nested within a `posrel` (`position: relative`) can be positioned with properties: `left`, `right`, `top`, and `bottom`.
4. It appears that OP needs `<i>` to move 20px to the left of its original position without disturbing the other tags (ie *"floating"*) `right: 20px` applied to `<i>` would move `<i>` 20px left from its parent tag's right border.
5. Also the `margin-top: -25px` applied to the parent tag looks like an attempt to keep `<i>` in the middle vertically. If so then add `top: 50%` to `<i>` and remove `margin-top: -25px` from `div.d-flex`.

#### Demo Features

1. boilerplate HTML for Bootstrap 4 (includes Font Awesome 5 stylesheet as well)
2. a `<form>` with two `<select>`.
3. `section#rowA.row select#A` is at default
4. `section#rowB.row select#B` is a corrected version of the one provided in question.

#### Corrections

1. `section#B div.col-md-8.d-flex`

   - added `position: relative`
   - removed `margin-top: -25px` (see **Problem #5**)
2. `section#B i.fas.fa-chevron-down`

   - replaced `margin-right: 20px` with `right: 20px`
   - added `position:absolute`
3. both `select`

   - removed `z-index: 2` (no idea why that would be useful)

I added a `<select>` at default to show how it looks when Bootstrap is properly configured. Do you really need the extra chevron?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap 4 Template</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.11.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <main class='container-fluid'>
    <form id='carform' class='form'>
      <section id='rowA' class='row'>
        <div class="d-flex  col-md-8">

          <select id="A" name="carlist" class="form-control" form="carform">
            <option value="">I have no idea</option>
            <option value=""></option>
          </select>

        </div>
        <div class='col-md-4'>Second Column</div>
      </section>

      <hr>

      <section id='rowB' class='row'>
        <div class="d-flex col-md-8" style="position: relative">

          <select id="B" name="carlist" class="form-control" form="carform">
            <option value="">I have no idea</option>
            <option value=""></option>
          </select>
          <i class="fas fa-chevron-down" style="pointer-events: none; right: 20px; position: absolute; z-index: 2;"></i>
        </div>
        <div class='col-md-4'>Second Column</div>

      </section>

    </form>
  </main>

  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```